# XUnit How To Exclude Tests From JetBrains dotCover

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, dotcover, runsettings

I have a solution with multiple unit tests projects.

And for code coverage i am using  JetBrains dotCover

[image]

So the goal here is to exclude the **Migrations** folder

I have added a runsettings file named **.runsettings** in the root of the test project

```
<Functions>
    <Exclude>
        <Function>^GF.Infrastructure\.Migrations\..*</Function>
    </Exclude>
</Functions>
```

however the Migrations namespace still appears in the coverage results, and i have to manually exclude it :

> You can also add new runtime filters right from the Unit Test
> Coverage: open the context menu for a desired node and then select
> Exclude and Create Runtime Coverage Filter.

like this : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/dotCover__Setting_up_Coverage_Filters.html#runtime_coverage_filters

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Rider

Go to *File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | dotCover | Filtering* and add an entry to *Do not analyze code in*:
[image]

## Visual Studio

Go to *ReSharper | Options | dotCover | Filtering* and add an entry to *Do not analyze code in*:
[image]

Comment: thank you, i already know this solution, my question was about the support of the file .runsettings, apparrently only MsTests support it